# Returning a different class pointer by overloaded operator new in a class

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, new-operator

Suppose i have this sample code:

```
class A
{
public:
     static void* operator new(size_t sz);

private:
int xA;
float yA;
};

class B : public A
{
private:
int xB;
float yB;
};

void* A::operator new(size_t sz)
{
   void* ptr = (void*)new B();
   return ptr;
}

int main()
{
B* b = (B*) new A();
// Use b ..
delete b;
return 0;
}
```

Here the constructors will be called in that order (tested in VS2012):

- A constructor
- B constructor
- A constructor

The first two constructors calls are because of the `new B()` in the overloaded operator new function. 
But then the A constuctor will be called again on the pointer returned by the function because the overloaded operator new is supposed to return a pointer to free memory (without creating the object), so the constructor is called again.

If i use the pointer `b` in this example, is this undefined behaviour?

Comment: you are supposed to return raw memory. There is a difference between operator new, and the new expression (that will also invoke a ctor)

Comment: Overloading the `new` and `delete` operators for `A` to create/destroy a `B` object is just horrid all the way around!

Comment: Something is wrong here.  As posted, the code has endless recursion. `B` inherits `operator new` from `A`, so the `new B()` expression in `A::operator new` calls `A::operator new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted has endless recursion, since you call
`A::operator new` from within `A::operator new`; class `B`
inherits the `operator new` from `A`.

Beyond that, you lie to the compiler, which results in undefined
behavior.  After `new A`, you have a pointer to an object whose
type is `A`.  You can legally convert its address to a `B*`, but
all you can do with that `B*` is convert it back to an `A*`;
anything else is undefined behavior.

And it's not clear what you're trying to achieve with the `new
B` in `A::operator new`.  The compiler will consider any memory
returned from an `operator new` as raw memory; in this case, it
will construct an `A` object in it, and from then on out, all
you have is an `A` object.  Any attempt to use it as a `B`
object is undefined behavior.  (And of course, if you actually
need to destruct the `B` created in `A::operator new`, you can't
because you've overwritten it.

Finally: you don't have to declare `operator new` as `static`;
it implicily is, and it's idiomatic not to write the `static` in
this case.  Similarly, when assigning the results of `new B` to
a `void*`, the conversion is idiomatic, and it is idiomatic not
to make it explicit.  (It's also best to avoid the C style
casts, since they hide too many errors.)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I didn't want to use this code but just to know if that was undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In general , `operator new()` should not CREATE an object, it should create space for an object. Your code will overwrite a `B` object with an `A` object, and then use it as a `B` object, and yes, that would be "undefined" (probably covered in the docs under "casting an object to a different type that it wasn't originally created as).

This may appear to work in this particular case, but if the constructor of `B` is more complex (e.g. there are virtual functions in `B`), it would immediately fail to work correctly.

If you want to allocate memory for an object, you could do:L

```
void* A::operator new(size_t sz)
{
   void* ptr = (void*)::new unsigned char[sz];
   return ptr;
}
```

Now you are not calling two different constructors for the same object!

Comment: Just a nit, but despite his claims, his code never called any constructor for anything; it goes into an endless recursion before getting to the first constructor call.

Comment: Uhm, I was thinking that it may do, due to the lack of :: in front of the new (which I added).

Comment: It's a good precaution.  Although in your case, not necessary, because the `operator new` is looked up in the scope of the object being constructed (or the element type in the case of `new[]`), and not in the scope of where the invocation occurs.  (Of course, when I want raw memory, I'll call `::operator new( sz )` directly.  I seems to make the purpose more explicit.  And in this case, you would need the `::`, since this is just an everyday function call.)

Answer (score 1):

The contract of `operator new` is just the memory allocation, the initialization is done later by the *new-expression* (by calling the constructor) or by program code if you call the operator directly.

What you are trying to do cannot be done, not like that. You could redesign to use a factory member function that would return a pointer to a `B` object, for example...